# Simular pulsación de 3 teclas con PowerShell

Tags: windows, bash, script, cmd, powershell

Estoy haciendo un script para que se pulsen 3 teclas en el teclado automáticamente con PowerShell. He logrado que se pulsen 2 teclas (Control y letra "G") pero no se como introducir a ese script que se pulse también la tecla Mayus, ya que no se cual es el código para esta tecla.

El script:

`[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{g}")`

El "^" simula el control; la "g" simula la letra "G"; pero no se cuál es el "código" para la tecla Mayús y no la encuentro por ningún sitio.

A ver si alguien sabe qué código puede tener la tecla Mayu en Windows.

Gracias.

Saludos.

Comment: Consulta de ignorante: No podrías ser `"^{G}"`?

Comment: Eso es exactamente lo mismo que Control + G, necesito que se pulse también la tecla Shift.

Answer (score 1):

Según: ["Converting the Windows Script Host SendKeys Method"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ff731008(v=technet.10)) puedes enviar los siguientes modificadores de teclas:

```
Key     Code
------- -------
SHIFT   +
CTRL    ^
ALT     %
```

En tu caso podrías probar con:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^+{g}")
```